# Security to Wcf Service hosted on windows service with NetNamedPipeBinding

Tags: wcf, windows-services, wcf-security, netnamedpipebinding

I have created a WCF service which is hosted on a windows service over NetNamedPipeBinding protocol.Now I want to provide security to this service, as in users with username and passwords known only should access this service.So how do I provide a method level authentication to users to access this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetNamedPipe binding doesn't support message level security out of the box. That would require custom binding. NetNamedPipe binding works only when both service and client are running on the same machine so there is assumption that if user has permissions to log in and the service is running she have also permission to call it. If you need to restrict users who can call the service you can always use custom [authorization manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731774.aspx) or [role based security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/765xy944%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).